# How Basic Load Balancer Work?

Tags: webserver, load-balancing

I want to make a simple code to load balance my 2 vps.
I want to make a load balancer for vps, not for the apache webserver or mysql.
And I want to use the third small vps to load balance my 2 vps, and I will add more in the future.
Can you guys point me the basic how load balancer work?
Is it just forwarding the tcp connection?
Any link is really appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The easiest way would be a round-robin DNS database.

Server:

- a.example.com (1.1.1.1)
- b.example.com (2.2.2.2)
- c.example.com (3.3.3.3)

The DNS-record would look like this:

```
example.com.   1800  IN  A  1.1.1.1
example.com.   1800  IN  A  2.2.2.2
example.com.   1800  IN  A  3.3.3.3
```

Whenever a user wants to resolve the hostname example.com the DNS server gives you the full list of addresses and your resolver chooses one.

First DNS answer would be 1.1.1.1 ... second userDNS request would get a 2.2.2.2

Comment: Close, except one hostname would be assigned to (have A or AAAA records for) all the IPs.

Comment: Did some more research. Seems like the usual DNS-server returns the full list of records (in random order) and the resovler must choose. Anyway, i am not familar with the DNS-server-software, so I am not sure about the 'random order' behavior.

Comment: Over large numbers of requests, it will tend to average out to being balanced, at least if the server software implementation itself isn't buggy.  When programming against the resolver API on the client side, it's often easiest to just take the first address returned (in an array), so it usually works out.

Comment: Thought so .. BTW: this method is also used against spam by adding a few invalid MX records